# How to assign a variable to a Matplotlib visual passed from PandasAI in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, chatbot, openai-api

So, I'm building a chatbot that utilizes PandasAI and OpenAI to analyze a dataset and provide insights. It's also used to provide visuals. My challenge is to display any visuals into my GUI, as the charts are having *NonType*. Following is the code to help you understand the issue:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasai import PandasAI
from pandasai.llm.openai import OpenAI

df = pd.read_csv('Demo.csv')

OPENAI_API_KEY = 'OPEN_AI_TOEKN'
llm = OpenAI(api_token = OPENAI_API_KEY)

def ask(prompt, data = df):

    pandas_ai = PandasAI(llm)
    response = pandas_ai.run(data, prompt)
    return response

my_chart = ask('Plot a line chart that shows total amount by month')

print(type(my_chart))
```

The output I'm getting: *NonType* and because of this I can't set my conditions to have it displayed on my GUI, and I can't even print it back using *print(my_chart)*, as only when I call the function the chart is displayed on my EDI (VS Code) but the chart doesn't seem to be stored in the variable in the first place.